# Bitte Türe schließen oder Bitte Tür schließen?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Why do some people write these differently? And does it mean "Please close the door" or "Please keep the door closed"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Türe" is an old-fashioned variation, "Tür" is standard today (and usage of "Türe" is fading away progressively in my experience. I haven't seen it in a while now).

In both cases, the correct translation is "Please close the door". If you want to say "Please keep the door closed", it's "Bitte [lass/lassen Sie] die Tür(e) geschlossen".

Comment: Why can it be "Bitte lass Sie.." if Sie here is formal you?

Comment: The options divide by the slash are "lass" and "lassen Sie": "Bitte lass die Tür(e) geschlossen" or "Bitte lassen Sie die Tür(e) geschlossen".

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I will clarify it.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Duden, "[Tür](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tuer)" is the more common word, while "[Türe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tuere)" is rather regionally, espically in middle Germany.

It's meaning is "Please close the door." "Please keep the door closed" would be

> Bitte Tür geschlossen halten.

Comment: As a native speaker would not use Bitte Tür geschlossen halten, I prefer Bitte halten Sie die Tür geschlossen or Bitte die Tür geschlossen halten

Comment: @Uwe Ich hatte hier eher ein Schild mit dieser Aufschrift vor Augen, keine gesprochene Aussage. Sonst gebe ich dir Recht.

Comment: "Tür zu!"? ;-) ........

Answer (score 4):

While in most regions we say [*die Tür*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/T%C3%BCr) the alternative from *[die Türe](https://www.dwds.de/wb/T%C3%BCre)* is used regionally.

This is a remnant from the Old High German **turi** in these regions.